# How to Configure Virtual Display with Multiple Physical with Modesetting Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, virtualization, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I have 2 physical displays mirrored and then a VIRTUAL1 display as primary for remoting in with Teamviewer. This is necessary, so that the physical displays could maintain a browser screen full sized and customers would not be interrupted by remotely logging in and using the VIRTUAL display for troubleshooting.

I have upgraded to Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3LTS following instructions at https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc-desktop .   The modesetting video driver is now used by default and my virtual display no longer works.

The option I have found is to disable modesetting.  My question is Is there a way to keep modesetting with 2 physical and 1 virtual display? I do have additional physical ports available

Here is some information about my device and drivers.

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: ASRock
    driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: DP-1,HDMI-A-1
    empty: DP-2,DP-3,HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a49
    class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9
    driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2160x3840 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 572x1016mm (22.5x40.0")
    s-diag: 1166mm (45.9")
  Monitor-1: DP-1 pos: primary,1-1 model: LG (GoldStar) Ultra HD
    serial: 259812 built: 2023 res: 2160x3840 hz: 60 dpi: 161 gamma: 1.2
    size: 340x600mm (13.4x23.6") diag: 690mm (27.2") ratio: 16:9 modes:
    max: 3840x2160 min: 640x480
  Monitor-2: HDMI-1 mapped: HDMI-A-1 pos: primary,1-1 model: ASM-156UC
    built: 2021 res: 2160x3840 hz: 60 dpi: 149 gamma: 1.2
    size: 369x620mm (14.5x24.4") diag: 685mm (27") ratio: 16:9 modes:
    max: 3840x2160 min: 720x400
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```

I was able to resolve my issue by enabling the virtual kernel mode setting (vkms) kernel module.

```
if [ -z "$(grep vkms /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf)" ]; then
      echo "Enable Virtual Kernal Mode Setting (VKMS) permanently"
      echo "vkms" | tee -a /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
    fi

    if [ -z "$(lsmod | egrep "^vkms")" ]; then
      echo "Enable Virtual Kernal Mode Setting (VKMS) for current session"
      modprobe vkms
    fi
fi
```

Once the vkms kernel module was enabled, running xrandr you should see the virtual display.  I then added the resolution I needed and used the Virtual monitor as an output with xrandr

```
xrandr --addmode ${VIRTUAL_LABEL} 3840x2160

xrandr --fb 4320x3840 --output ${HDMI_LABEL} --mode 3840x2160  --rotation left  --output ${VIRTUAL_LABEL} --mode 3840x2160 --primary --rotation left --right-of ${HDMI_LABEL}
```